# Button not executing window.location

Tags: javascript, button

Im actually having a problem with html5 button in visualforce pages. I have a requirement where when i click on a button, it should redirect to a certain page (user do not want link). For some reason which i don't know, the function i'm executing do not work with HTML5 button (in fact the page only refresh but do not redirect) but when i use input of type button, the function is executed as expected.

I want to use the html5 button as there are some specific css already defined for button in the plugin im using. Find below codes for my button and javascript function :

```
  <button class="butt" onclick="newContact()" >Nouveau</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     function newContact(){
        window.location = "/apex/VFP01_NewContact";
     }
 </script>
```

What did I do wrong here, and what is the limitation of html5 button ?

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I tested with your code in both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox under Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to know the answer. In visualforce page, the html5 button execute a submit of my form. A way to prevent this, was to specify the attribute type="button".

Answer (score 0):

You really have two options.

You could consider wrapping a  element with an anchor  tag that points to the URL that you want to target as seen below :

```
    <!-- Target the "YourAction" action in your "YourController" controller -->
<a href='@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")'>
    <input type="Button" id="mybutton" name="url button" value="Next" />
</a>
```

or you could handle this purely through Javascript and perform your navigation that way :

```
<!-- The onclick event will trigger a Javascript call to navigate -->
<input type="Button" id="mybutton" name="url button" value="Next" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")';" />
```

Comment: I want to use html5 button and not input type= button. With input type=button it works fine. but its when i execute it using <button> that it doesnt work. Infact the function is called, but the window.location do not redirect to the specified url . it just refreshes my page. For info, im using this code in visualforce page and not purely html page. But i can't figure out how it do make any difference.